# Not getting the clusters after reading the dataset and using spectral clustering

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-science

After reading the dataset and using spectral clustering, I am not getting the clusters:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('googledataset.csv',header=0)
print(df.values)
df=df.dropna()
test_df=df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
cluster = SpectralClustering(affinity='rbf', assign_labels='kmeans', coef0=1,degree=3, eigen_solver=None, eigen_tol=0.0, gamma=1.0,kernel_params=None, n_clusters=2, n_init=10, n_jobs=None,
            n_neighbors=10, random_state=0).fit(df)
test_df['clusters'] = cluster.labels_
print('Results', test_df['clusters'])
```

Comment: Explain your question in briefly, With the error that you have

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr i have edited the question so that it is more understandable. I am not getting any error. but i am not getting the clusters

Comment: @Yoshitha Penaganti any idea on this

Answer (score 0):

Put `fit` in a separate line.

The method doesn't return the clustering object.

Comment: It doesn't work. If I try to print any thing calling the spectral clustering I can't see it in the console. @Anony-Mousse

Comment: Well, what do you get then? We don't see your screen.